# I can't trigger the modal component to open from a different component

Tags: react-native

I declared a Modal component in a separate js file and I'm trying to make it appear when an onPress event happens. I can't seem to be able to toggle that.

I Googled and found [React Native open modal from different component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50466903/react-native-open-modal-from-different-component) but either I'm not getting something or that doesn't work for me.

I have the following `modal.js`:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
  Modal,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TouchableHighlight,
  View,
  Alert
} from 'react-native';
import config from '../config/colors';

export default class ModalWindow extends Component {
  state = {
    modalVisible: false,
  };


  setModalVisible(visible) {
    this.setState({modalVisible: visible});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Modal
          animationType="fade"
          transparent={false}
          visible={this.state.modalVisible}
          onDismiss={() => {
            console.log('Modal has been closed.');
          }}>
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <View>
              <Text>Hello World!</Text>

              <TouchableHighlight
                onPress={() => {
                  this.setModalVisible(!this.state.modalVisible);
                }}>
                <Text>Hide Modal!</Text>
              </TouchableHighlight>
            </View>
          </View>
        </Modal>

        <TouchableHighlight
          onPress={() => {
            this.setModalVisible(true);
          }}>
          <Text>Show Modal</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    position: 'absolute',
    marginTop: 22
  }
});
```

And inside a separate file I have:

```
import Modal from '../components/modal';
```

and declared the  component inside my render as such

```
... other stuff ...

<View style={styles.modalContainer}>
          <Modal isModalVisible={this.state.modalVisible}></Modal>
</View>

... other stuff ...
```

finally, I have a button set such that this gets called: `onPressAvatar={this.onPressAvatar}`

and that method is:

```
onPressAvatar = props => {
    console.log("press avatar");
    this.setState({modalVisible: true});
  }
```

I know the onPress works because the `console.log()` gets triggered but the modal doesn't appear. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use props to open/close your modal like this:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
  Modal,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TouchableHighlight,
  View,
  Alert
} from 'react-native';
import config from '../config/colors';

export default class ModalWindow extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Modal
          animationType="fade"
          transparent={false}
          visible={this.props.isModalVisible}
          onDismiss={() => {
            console.log('Modal has been closed.');
          }}>
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <View>
              <Text>Hello World!</Text>

              <TouchableHighlight
                onPress={() => {
                  this.props.close();
                }}>
                <Text>Hide Modal!</Text>
              </TouchableHighlight>
            </View>
          </View>
        </Modal>

        <TouchableHighlight
          onPress={() => {
            this.setModalVisible(true);
          }}>
          <Text>Show Modal</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Note that I change `this.state.modalVisible` to `this.props.modalVisible` and I remove the methods that set the states

Here you pass your state values

```
... other stuff ...

<View style={styles.modalContainer}>
          <Modal isModalVisible={this.state.modalVisible} close={this.setState({modalVisible: false})}></Modal>
</View>

... other stuff ...
```

And now your component is controlled by your Parent component that  changes its own state and propagate to your Modal.

A component has props and states, props are immutable objects that the component receives when you pass data by setting attributes like `<Modal isModalVisible={value} />`. They become available to your component by the property **this.props**. On the other hand the State property is used to control the internal state of the component and each state change using this.setState causes a new rendering call. So in your code we need to set Parent component **State** to notify all the components children that there are changes. Then your Modal component will call its own method render to show or hidden the modal box.

Comment: So just got me to better understand, it's left as a state in the parent controller because I want the change to happen there but becomes props on the component itself to be modifiable?

Comment: Yep, almost that. I'll edit the answer to add more information

Comment: I tried explain a little more and I fix some problems in the code example.